# how to perfome query to cache data before sending

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am using [apicache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache) to cache data which is working fine using this code

```
import express from 'express'
import apicache from 'apicache'

let app = express()
let cache = apicache.middleware

app.get('/api/collection/:id?', cache('5 minutes'), (req, res) => {
  // do some work... this will only occur once per 5 minutes
  res.json({ foo: 'bar' })
})
```

now my problem is in another route which is `"/api/checkAvalability"`, i want to get the cache data from this route `'/api/collection/:id?'` and check if the `foo` value `contains "a"` before sending back to users